# Is there a proof using Brouwer's fixed-point theorem for the closed unit disc and punctured (centre removed) closed disc being non-homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ and  $\mathbb{D}_0=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 0<x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. I know how to prove that they are not homeomorphic, even the fundamental groups are different. But I wish to prove this using Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

What I was thinking that, if we assume existence of a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}_0$, then we may be able to find a continuous map $g:\mathbb{D}_0\to\mathbb{D}$ such that $g\circ f$ does not have any fixed points.

Is it possible?

Comment: Neither of these spaces has the fixed point property. Brouwer's theorem applies to the **closed** unit disc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry for the mistake, I made an edit.

Comment: Now, one space has the fixed-point property, the other hasn't. One space is compact, the other isn't.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, that's true. There'are several other ways to prove the non-existence of a homeomorphism. But I want it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f{:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}_0}$ and $g{:\mathbb{D}_0\to \mathbb{D}}$ be any pair of continuous functions such that $g(f(x)) = x$ on $\mathbb{D}$. Then $x\mapsto g(-f(x))$ is continuous on $\mathbb{D}$ and therefore has a fixed point $x_0$. Then $$g(-f(x_0)) = x_0 = g(f(x_0))$$ and since $f(x_0)\neq 0$ this shows that no such $g$ can be injective and no such $f$ can be surjective. In particular neither $g$ nor $f$ can be a homeomorphism.

Comment: That's a perfect answer! Thanks..:)